# Talend-error-capturing

Tags: java, mysql, sql, talend

How to capture failed records(example foreign key contraint/parent table not found/unique key Constraint etc)????
After capturing those failed records I need to send an email notification along with count of failed records and message to why that records failed..??

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no information about the db, I assume MySQL. In MySQL you can de-select in the **tMySQLOutput** the option *Extended Insert*. Now it is possible with a right click on the component to get a *Reject* link.

NOTE: *The performance of the insert will go down drastically because every row has to be inserted and checked*

Those rejected rows can be catched with a *tLogCatcher* component. The information can be send with a **tSendMail** component.

Comment: Thank You! It did helped me.

Comment: difficulty in configuration setting of Component "tOracleOutput" & "tOracleBulkExec" My database is Oracle 32bit. Irrespective of Source i'm unable to set the property type or 'use an existing connection' Also I always have some issues with Oracle based components(so i had to opt for tjdbcinput/tjdbcoutput) Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answer helped you, consider marking this answer as accepted. Regarding the problems with the components, open another question with screenshots at best.

Comment: i have added screenshots in my next question.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends where do You want to capture errors, if You're using something like file parser You can start from capturing errors there, later as other mentioned:

- Use existing connection
- Avoid bulk insert ( performance is very low )

https://fullouterjoin.wordpress.com/2019/01/10/two-levels-of-error-logging-in-talend-cloud/